# Adding string to registry path regopenkeyex

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, registry

Hey so let's say this is the code :

```
HKEY hk;
long n = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,L"SOFTWARE\\",
                  0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hk );
if ( n == ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
    cout << "Found ! " << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Failed with value " << n << endl;
}
RegCloseKey(hk);
```

So I have a variable string that i need to add to the path that might looks like this :

```
 string s = "test";
```

How to make L"SOFTWARE\\" + s  as a path?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you tried:

```
long n = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\" + s, ... );
```

Which probably gave you a compiler warning. Since you need to add a variable string to the path, you can use:

```
const std::string sFullPath = "SOFTWARE\\" + s;
long n = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sFullPath.c_str(), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hk);
```

This works because [`RegOpenKeyEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897(v=vs.85).aspx) takes a `const char*` as its argument.